# $uibModalProvider is unknown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui.bootstrap

I am working with `angular-ui-bootstrap`. I get this error:

> Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- WebAppController

## Information

1- Have used `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency in my app correctly.

```
angular.module('webApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

2- Have injected `$uibModal` in the controller .

```
angular.module('webApp').
controller( 
    'WebAppController',
    ['webAppService', '$uibModal',
    function WebAppController(webAppService, $uibModal) {
        # more code here..............
}])
```

3. Using angularJs version `1.6.4` and [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-bootstrap) version `2.5.0`.

I would be extremely happy if somebody helps figure out the issue.

Comment: Error is handled on $uibModal call ?

Comment: I have not yet used `$uibModal` in the controller: I have only injected it.

Comment: are you using any dependency management? post your index.html where you load the scripts

Comment: @svarog No. I have used CDN.

Answer (score 0):

This was a careless mistake. For this project, I had three files : `webApp.module.js`, `webApp.controller.js` and  `webApp.router.js`. I had used  `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency in `webApp.module.js` and `webApp.controller.js`.

You need only use dependencies in one of your file.